# vuejs create tooltip showing all tooltips

Tags: vue.js, tooltip, vuejs2, show-hide

hi guys im just learning vuejs and its event in list.
im wondering how can i show/hide components (in this example, a div) as tooltip?

i did this

```
<ul id="example-1">
  <li v-for="item in items">
    <div v-on:mouseover="tooltipActive = !tooltipActive">hover me</div>
    <div class="tooltip" v-if="tooltipActive">{{ item.name }}</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

and i set `tooltipActive: false` in data. the problem is when i hover 1 list item, all tooltips in all items are showing.. (of course)

do you have any idea on how to solve this kind of sample?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
console.clear()

new Vue({
  el: "#example-1",
  data:{
    items: [
      {name: "item one"},
      {name: "item two"},
      {name: "item three"}
    ],
    activeItem: null
  }
})
```

```css
li {cursor: pointer}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.2"></script>
<ul id="example-1">
  <li v-for="item in items">
    <div v-on:mouseover="activeItem = item" 
          v-on:mouseout="activeItem = null">
        hover me
    </div>
    <div class="tooltip" v-if="activeItem === item">{{ item.name }}</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: ah make sense! thanks bert! btw is this a correct way of thinking of vuejs? (because honestly im more jquery coder and i see my approach is so jquery)

Comment: @bondythegreat This is definitely a vue style approach; the UI is driven by state.